# MongoDB Atlas - admin user not authorized to run commands in the shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell

I've setup a replicat set mongoDB in mongoDB Atlas.

I can connect to the cluster woth `mongosh` but can't execute command like `rs.status()` or even `show users`.
I'm getting the below error:

```
Atlas atlas-lmkye1-shard-0 [primary] wtlive-staging> rs.status()
MongoServerError: not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetGetStatus: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("d888f98f-5b92-4fdf-836d-8c8ad86df659") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1674659350, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 611CAD1FEBDB879CD8C71265AF6CD769AFDC37DA), keyId: 7160608903690977282 } }, $db: "admin" }
Atlas atlas-lmkye1-shard-0 [primary] wtlive-staging> show dbs
admin           424.00 KiB
config          220.00 KiB
local            13.37 GiB
monstache       160.00 KiB
wtlve-staging   18.23 GiB
Atlas atlas-lmkye1-shard-0 [primary] wtlive-staging> show users
MongoServerError: not authorized on waiter-staging to execute command { usersInfo: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("d888f98f-5b92-4fdf-836d-8c8ad86df659") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1674659934, 11), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 4BA4C6CC9223F392114A1148663017143E15D3CD), keyId: 7160608903690977282 } }, $db: "wtlive-staging" }
Atlas atlas-lmkye1-shard-0 [primary] wtlive-staging>
```

With my onpremise MondbDB i don't have this issue. Any idea of what could be the matter?

Comment: What is the output of `db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo`?

Comment: Atlas atlas-lmkye1-shard-0 [primary] wtlive-staging> db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo
{
  authenticatedUsers: [ { user: 'nixmind', db: 'admin' } ],
  authenticatedUserRoles: [ { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' } ]
}
Atlas atlas-lmkye1-shard-0 [primary] wtlive-staging>

Comment: `nixmind` is the user I added when creating the cluster in the MongoDB Atlas GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a careful look at [Built-In Roles: readWriteAnyDatabase](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-readWriteAnyDatabase)

Action `replSetGetStatus` requires [clusterManager](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-clusterManager)

Action `usersInfo` requires [userAdmin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-userAdmin)

Comment: You're right, I edited the user and selected `Atlas admin` Built-in role in user privileges from Atlas GUI.